# Given $f'$ is continuous and $(f'(0))^2>3$, what can I say about $f'(x)$ near $0$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

I'm working on problem where I want to use the continuity of $f'$ to assert that $f'(x)$ cannot be zero ("bounded away from zero"?) near $x = 0$.  We know that $(f'(0))^2 >3$.

So, I think that what I really want to ask is this:  if $f'$ is cts, must $f'$-squared also be continuous?

Can I use the epsilon-delta definition?:

Since $f'$ is continuous, for every $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that:

$$|x-0|<\delta \implies|f'(x)-f'(0)|<\epsilon$$
$$ \implies -\epsilon < f'(x) - f'(0) < \epsilon $$
$$ \implies f'(0)-\epsilon < f'(x)   < f'(0)+\epsilon $$

From here I'm not sure how to use the fact that $(f'(0))^2>3$.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(0)^2>3\implies |f'(0)|>\sqrt{3}$

However, the function is continuous at $x=0$, so for some $\delta$, we have $|f'(x)-f'(0)|<\sqrt{3}$ whenever $|x|<\delta$.

However, this asserts that, $|f'(0)-f'(x)|<\sqrt{3}\implies |f'(0)|-|f'(x)|<\sqrt{3}$ by using the triangle inequality.

Thus, we have,

$|f'(x)|>|f'(0)|-\sqrt{3}>\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{3}=0$ whenever $|x|<\delta$.

Thus, we reach the conclusion that $f$ is bounded away from $0$ near $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks so much Hasan.  Nice usage of the reverse triangle inequality :-)

Answer (score 2):

Well, $x\mapsto f'(x)$ is continuous, and $y\mapsto y^2$ is also continuous, so what can you say about $x\mapsto\left( f'(x)\right)^2$?

Answer (score 2):

Very generally, if $f$ and $g$ are both continuous functions, then $f \circ g$ is a continuous function. (If you haven't proved this, then you should). Here, you are composing the square-function with the derivative of $f$.